# Using an stack inside recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures

I need to use an stack in a recursive function. Between function recursive calls the stack has to keep the contents and only modified by push or pop operations inside the function.

A way to do this it to define a global stack variable like this:

```
StackPtr stack = createStack();
```

Another way is to pass an stack to the function:

```
int recursiveFunction(int n, StackPtr stack);
```

Is there a way to do this but without global stack or passing an stack to the function? The idea is to encapsulate completely the function so the user just has to call it independently of the program specifications. It is like to define an static stack that conserve the stacks contents between recursive calls.

I tried:

```
int recursiveFunction(int n){
    static StackPtr stack = NULL;
    stack = createStack();
...
}
```

But the function reset the stack each call. I had to create the stack in the way shown because if I put:

```
static StackPtr stack = createStrack();
```

An "not initialized constant" error is thrown.

Thanks.

Comment: May be static local? I would pass the stack structure pointer as an argument. Also, what is 'StackPtr' is it a class?

Comment: You can add a boolean variable `initialized` with initial value of `false` to your try with the static stack. If it is `false` (will be so on the first call), create the stack and mark it `true`.

Comment: Not directly related, but I'd rethink the design. If you use an explicit stack, why do you need recursion in the first place? :o

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize static pointer with malloc in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724801/how-to-initialize-static-pointer-with-malloc-in-c)

Comment: But each return addres, recursive or not, each local stack frame, recursive or not, each saved group of machine registers are stored/pushed an then back popped from the system global stack setup by the program loader and/or startup code before main() is called.

Comment: s7amuser: The "initialized" flag works too. Thanks.

Comment: Felix Palmen: I need to reverse an integer number without using concatenation or converting an string to integer. If the user enters 1234 the output is 4321. So what I did was to create a recursive function where the every digit of the input number is pushed to an stack. Then every element of the stack is popped into an acumulator that keeps suming the numbers multiplied for a 10 power.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual solution is to use a helper function. The main function creates the stack (or whatever object is necessary), calls the helper (which is the actual recursive function) and then frees the stack before returning:

```
static int helper(StackPtr stack, int n) {
    ... /* Recursive calls to helper */
}

int mainFunction(int n){
    StackPtr stack = createStack();
    int rv = helper(stack, n)
    freeStack(stack);
    return rv;
}
```

Using a local static variable should normally be avoided since it makes the function non-reentrant and thread-unsafe.

Comment: If the `createStack` and `freeStack` functions are expensive, this may not be the best solution. I upvoted this answer anyway.

Comment: I wanted to avoid calling the function with an stack parameter.

Comment: @carlitos_30: you call the main function, so the caller doesn't need to know anything about stacks. The rest is an implementation detail.

Comment: @michael: if the stack functions are expensive, they themselves could recycle stacks using a mutex-protected pool. However, it is very rare for that to be worthwhile.

Comment: @rici I understood what you meant. I confused the "mainFunction", with the "main" function. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
int recursiveFunction(int n){
  static StackPtr stack;

  if (stack == NULL)
    stack = createStack();

  ...
}
```

Upon startup, `stack`is initialized to `NULL`.
The first time `recursiveFunction` is called, `stack` will be initialized. That's it.

But if thread safety is required, this solution won't work.